# How to use php code on a botton created with WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to know something.

Like if I have created page like this =>

https://www.globalfreelanceacademy.com/cpages-ebook/

with wordpress webpage creating tool like "instabuilder" and wanted to use this link =>

```html
<a href = '<?php echo ("https://paystack.com/pay/".get_pname($_GET["pid"]));?>'>
Download And Enjoy!!!</a>
```

on the "Download And Enjoy!!!" button, since neither the webpage builder (instabuilder) nor wordpress support using php on page, how will I edit that from the `wordpress` database or is there any other place to edit it with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin - for example [Insert PHP Code Snippet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/) and create a shortcode for your link and insert the shortcode in the post.

Here is a screenshot from the plugin where you can add your php code:

[image]

and how you can use these shortcodes:

[image]